# How to sign text message using public key in web3j?

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3j

I can sign a text message using public key in web3js

```
const signature = await this.web3.eth.personal.sign(
            loginMessage,
            publicAddress,
            ""
        )
```

What would be its web3j equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

In `Web3J`, we have the following [`Sign`](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/master/crypto/src/main/java/org/web3j/crypto/Sign.java) class. It has multiple static methods that you can use to create signatures.
For example:

```
import org.web3j.crypto.Credentials;
import org.web3j.crypto.Sign;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Credentials credentials = Credentials.create("0x1234");
        byte[] msg = "hello".getBytes();
        Sign.SignatureData signature = Sign.signMessage(msg, credentials.getEcKeyPair());
        // do what you want with the signature
    }
}
```

The return of `Sign.signMessage(...)` is a [`SignatureData`](https://github.com/web3j/web3j/blob/d4278f54157744f622d889ec29e91ce090fc0564/crypto/src/main/java/org/web3j/crypto/Sign.java#L346) instance which contains the [`r`, `s` and `v`](https://medium.com/mycrypto/the-magic-of-digital-signatures-on-ethereum-98fe184dc9c7) values.

Comment: Also, this issue discusses multiple ways to sign stuff using the library: https://github.com/web3j/web3j/issues/208

Comment: Is this "personal_sign" or "eth_sign" though?